# $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} {(1-\cos(\sin 1/n))}^{w}$ with $w$ as parameter

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Let $f(x)=(1-\cos(\sin x))$; $a_n=f(1/n)$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}$

For which $w>0$ series $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} {a_n}^{w}$$ converge?

I haven't got a slicest idea how to check that, absolutely none (besides Cauchy's criterion but that seems to be unwise here). Please guys, help.

Comment: $\dfrac{1-\cos t}2=\sin^2\dfrac t2$ and $\sin u\approx u$ when $u\to0$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To understand the behavior of $a_n$, notice that
$$
f(x)=\frac{x^2}{2}+O(x^4)
$$
as $x \to 0$. Hence $a_n \approx \frac{1}{2n^2}$ as $n \gg 1$. Therefore you can compare $a_n^w$ to $n^{-2w}$ when $n \gg 1$.

Comment: Yes, I got the same thing.

Comment: Incredible, I'd never thought about that. Thank you very much.